# Django: no such table: auctions_user_user_permissions

Tags: python, html, sql, django, sqlite

I wrote the Django program and registered some products with the admin panel.
After making some changes in the codes, I encountered some problems:
1- It is no longer possible to enter the admin panel and it gives this error.
2- None of the product information is displayed and it seems as if there is no data on the site.

what is the problem?

VIEWS.PY:

```
# item detail page in views.py
def item_detail(request, bidid):
    bid_desc = List.objects.get(pk = bidid, active_bool=True)
    nowbids = Bidmodel.objects.filter(listb_id = bidid)
    
    return render(request, "auctions/item_detail.html",{
        "list": bid_desc,
        "comments" : Comments.objects.filter(listc_id = bidid),
        "now_bid": minbid(bid_desc.first_bid, nowbids),
})



# winner
def winner(request):
    bid_id = request.GET["listid"]
    nowbids = Bidmodel.objects.filter(listb_id = bid_id)
    biddesc = List.objects.get(pk = bid_id)
    maxbid = minbid(biddesc.first_bid, nowbids)

    try:
        winner_who = Bidmodel.objects.get(bid = maxbid, listb_id = bid_id)
        winner_list = List.objects.get(id = bid_id)
        win = Winner(win_list = winner_list, user = winner_who.user)
        winners_name = winner_who.user
    
    except:
        winner_list = List.objects.get(first_bid = maxbid, id = bid_id)
        win = Winner(win_list = winner_list, user = winner_list.user)
        winners_name = winner_list.user

    biddesc.active_bool = False
    biddesc.save()
    win.save()
    messages.success(request, f"{winners_name} won {win.win_list.title}.")
    return redirect("index")



# check winner
def winner_check(request):
    try:
        yourwin = Winner.objects.filter(user = request.user.username)
    except:
        yourwin = None

    return render(request, "auctions/winner_check.html",{
        "user_winlist" : yourwin,
    })
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Active Listings</h2>

    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div>{{ message }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}

    <div>
        {% for item in items %}
            <div>
                <img src= {{ item.image.url }} alt = "{{item.title}}"><br>
                <a>{{ item.title }}</a><br>
                <a>{{ item.category }}</a><br>
                <a><a>Frist Bid: </a> {{ item.first_bid }} $ </a><br>
                <a href="{% url 'item_detail' item.id %}">View Product</a>
            </div>  
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

item_detail.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div>{{ message }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <img src= {{ list.image.url }} alt = "{{list.title}}"><br>
    <a><a>Product:</a>{{ list.title }}</a><br>
    <a><a>Category: </a>{{ list.category }}</a><br>
    <a><a>Desc: </a>{{ list.description }}</a><br>
    <a><a>Status: </a>{{ list.status }}</a><br>
    <a><a>Frist Bid: </a> {{ list.first_bid }} $ </a><br>
    <div><a><a>Current Bid: </a> {{ now_bid }} $ </div>
    <div><a><a>Listed By: </a> {{ list.user }}</div>
    


    <div>
        <form method= "get" action = "{% url "addwatchlist" %}">
            <button type = "submit" value = {{ list.id }} name = "listid" >Add to Watchlist</button>
        </form>
    </div>



    
    <form method = "get" action = "{% url "bid_check" %}">
        <input name = "bid_amnt" placeholder = "Bid Amount" type = "number">
        <button type = "submit" name = "list_d" value = {{ list.id }}>accept</button>
    </form>




    <h3>Comments</h3>
        <div>
            <ul>
                {% for comment in comments %}
                    <li><a><a>{{ comment.user }} : {{comment.comment}}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <form method = "get" action ="{% url "comments" %}">
            <input required type = "text" placeholder = "Add Comment" name = "comment">
            <button type = "submit" value = {{ list.id }} name = "listid"> Comment </button>
        </form>




        <div>
            {% if list.user == user.username %}
                <form method= "get" action = "{% url "winner" %}">
                    <button type = "submit" value = {{ list.id }} name = "listid" >Close Bid</button>
                </form>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
   
        
{% endblock %}
```

winner_check.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Your Winnings</h2>
    <div>
        {% for list in user_winlist %}
            <div>
                <img src={{ list.win_list.image.url }}><br>
                <a>Product:{{list.win_list.title}}</a><br>
                <a>Category:{{list.win_list.category}}</a><br>
                <a>Initial price:{{list.win_list.first_bid}}</a><br>
                <div>This bid was listed by <a>{{ list.win_list.user }}</a>.</div>
            </div>  
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
return super().execute(query, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

The above exception (no such table: auctions_user_user_permissions) was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
response = get_response(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper
return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapper_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 422, in login
**self.each_context(request),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 337, in each_context
"available_apps": self.get_app_list(request),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 536, in get_app_list
app_dict = self._build_app_dict(request, app_label)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 478, in _build_app_dict
has_module_perms = model_admin.has_module_permission(request)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 611, in has_module_permission
return request.user.has_module_perms(self.opts.app_label)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 331, in has_module_perms
return _user_has_module_perms(self, app_label)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 235, in _user_has_module_perms
if backend.has_module_perms(user, app_label):
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 121, in has_module_perms
for perm in self.get_all_permissions(user_obj)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 109, in get_all_permissions
user_obj._perm_cache = super().get_all_permissions(user_obj)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 27, in get_all_permissions
*self.get_user_permissions(user_obj, obj=obj),
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 96, in get_user_permissions
return self._get_permissions(user_obj, obj, "user")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\backends.py", line 87, in _get_permissions
user_obj, perm_cache_name, {"%s.%s" % (ct, name) for ct, name in perms}
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 398, in **iter**
self._fetch_all()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1881, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 246, in **iter**
return compiler.results_iter(

File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1511, in results_iter
results = self.execute_sql(

File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1560, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(

File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in **exit**
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Nazi\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute
return super().execute(query, params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/login/
Exception Value: no such table: auctions_user_user_permissions

Comment: Is 'auctions' in your INSTALLED_APPS? Did you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: @Lomtrur
yeah....I did

Comment: Please incldue the stacktrace you see. What changes did you make to your code after which this exception started to appear?

Comment: @Lomtrur  The person who has registered the product can close the auction at the price he wants and sell the product by clicking on the close bid button, and after this no one can register a bid on the product...
My initial code was not able to close the offer completely, and after determining the winner, it was possible to register the offer again.
I modified the code and encountered these errors.
After the errors, I deleted all the changes and returned the code to the original state, but it didn't work...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is all migrations are in-place? If you have deleted any migrations then that will be an issue. According to error it tried to find the table with name `auctions_user_user_permissions`, that might be an join table for auctions, user and user_permissions but not able to get any idea based on the details you have posted.

Comment: @AnkushChavan The models and tables have not been changed, and there have been changes in the files whose code I sent.
And from the beginning, I had not created any table or column with this name, and the admin panel and the program were working fine.

Comment: If that's the case, if it's not a prod database, could you revert all the migrations and deleted all migration files, and then create fresh migrations and apply that? That might work since you are saying you haven't created any tables yet, not sure though.

Comment: @AnkushChavan  So far, I have written several Django programs and none of them needed this management table, however, I created the table it wanted and the program works, but I did not understand where the problem is.